# Cryptic FCM 10.2.0 Failure - FirebaseInitProvider, NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to add Firebase Cloud Messaging to my app with no success, as I get the following exception:

```
1 27336-27336/com.company.here E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.company.here, PID: 27336
                                                                        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/com.company.here.debug-1/base.apk)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5883)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5475)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5414)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Here's what I've checked so far:

- google-services is set to 3.0.0 in the project gradle file
- I only have one dependency related to firebase, which is 10.2.0
- I have jack enabled so I can use lambdas
- I have ReactiveAndroid and Retrofit incorporated into the project, perhaps they're interacting badly? That said I didn't see anything suspicious when running `./gradlew app:dependencies`
- Tried `multiDexEnabled = true`, didn't make a difference
- Had a custom `applicationIdSuffix` for debug builds, attempted to remove it but it also didn't make a difference
- Positioning of `apply plug: 'com.google.gms.google-services` doesn't seem to matter, currently at end of gradle file

What could be causing this? As best as I can tell, `FirebaseInitProvider` is calling an internal static method from `attachInfo`, which in turn attempts to call out to a static method on an SDK-private class that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Do you have other google-play-services dependencies? If so they need to be to the same version of the firebase one. The error seems to suggest that you are in including Google libraries with different versions.

Comment: As I mentioned, nothing suspicious turned up when running ./gradlew app:dependencies. I don't doubt that might be a possibility, but unless it's a transitive dependency there's no obvious fault.

Answer (score 0):

So this was weird:

Nothing about my setup changed from last night except I ran the `clean project` command, added the `firebase-core` dependency and then built again, and everything started to work.

I had assumed that `firebase-messaging` pulled all of its dependencies in by itself, but that goes against the setup guide, and the crash makes sense if the internal class `FirebaseInitProvider` is attempting to access is in the `firebase-core` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a mismatch of one of your `play-services` dependencies and Firebase in your app level build.gradle.

Having google services at 3.0.0 in your project level build.gradle is fine (`com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`).

For example, if you have dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.0` they must both be the same version `10.2.0`.